# TortoiseSVN: Is there a conventional way to add link from commit message to other commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to make a commit with a message referencing to other commit I've made before.
For example, the message should be like:

```
It's a bugfix for a problem brought by commit #865
```

I'm looking for a way to do get "865" displayed as a link to previous commit that I can click and view (like the way it's possible for issue numbers from the bug tracking system intergrated with TortoiseSVN).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do this by simply typing the revision number you want to refer to like this:

```
r865
```

This feature was introduced in TortoiseSVN 1.7, so make sure you've got the right version.

Check the [1.7 release notes page](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#logdlg) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with Tortoise.
But when you enter "865" in Log search bar you'll find revisions whose number is "865" and that include "865" in their comment.